# Copenhagen at night

Tags: sightseeing, denmark, copenhagen

I will be in Denmark just for one night (23:00-6:00) but do not really know what to do there.

I guess it would be a waste of time just to go to hotel. I checked many travel guides but unfortunately they all suggest "bars, restaurants, disco" - is there anything I can do which is more historical/cultural?

The night of stay is Friday/Saturday.

Answer (score 6):

You won't find much, except bars and such, open at that hour.

You can of course visit many noteworthy buildings, if you are content to just see them from the outside. This includes [Christiansborg](http://www.christiansborg.dk/english/), [Amalienborg](http://dkks.dk/amalienborg-palace), [Marble Church](http://www.marmorkirken.dk/), Vor [Frelsers Kirke](http://www.vorfrelserskirke.dk/) and many others. There are also interesting landmarks such as Nyhavn and the statue of the Little Mermaid. I'd recommend reading up a bit so you'll have some context when walking around.

I'd also highly recommend a stroll down Strøget. It is a walking street that stretches from Nyhavn and almost to the main train station. On a Friday night it will be full of life and is certainly a part of Copenhagen's culture, even if it is not highbrow culture.

Comment: Dear Kris, thanks for the kind reply! I was looking for a nice place to stroll - I guess the Strøget is a good choice. Just one more question. Is it save at nights in Copenhagen? I mean I would be walking all alone and could accasionly go into a wrong/bad street? Many web sites state that it is pretty safe.

Comment: Copenhagen is very safe as cities go. If you stay near Stroget you'll be just fine. Head in the other direction from the central train station and you may encounter some less savory elements, but I've never felt unsafe anywhere in Copenhagen.